# Convert JSON to a multidimensional array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

How can I convert a string of JSON data to a multidimensional array?

```
# Begin with JSON
json_data = "[
  {"id":1,"name":"Don"},
  {"id":2,"name":"Bob"}, 
  ...
]"

# do something here to convert the JSON data to array of arrays.

# End with multidimensional arrays
array_data = [
  ["id", "name"],
  [1,"Don"],
  [2,"Bob"],
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For readability and efficiency, I would do it like this:

```
require 'json'

json_data = '[{"id":1,"name":"Don"},{"id":2,"name":"Bob"}]'

arr =  JSON.parse(json_data)
  #=> "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Don\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Bob\"}]"
keys = arr.first.keys
  #=> ["id", "name"]
arr.map! { |h| h.values_at(*keys) }.unshift(keys)
  #=> [["id", "name"], [1, "Don"], [2, "Bob"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
require 'json'
json_data = '[{"id":1,"name":"Don"},{"id":2,"name":"Bob"}]'
JSON.parse(json_data).inject([]) { |result, e| result + [e.keys, e.values] }.uniq
```

First, we read the JSON into an array with `JSON.parse`. For each element in the JSON, we collect all keys and values using `inject` which results in the following array:

```
[
  ["id", "name"],
  [1, "Don"],
  ["id", "name"],
  [2, "Bob"]
]
```

To get rid of the repeating key-arrays, we call `uniq` and are done.

```
[
  ["id", "name"],
  [1, "Don"],
  [2, "Bob"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @tessi's answer, we can avoid using 'uniq' if we combine 'with_index' and 'inject'.

```
require 'json'
json_data = '[{"id":1,"name":"Don"},{"id":2,"name":"Bob"}]'
array_data =  JSON.parse(json_data).each.with_index.inject([]) { |result, (e, i)|  result + (i == 0 ? [e.keys, e.values] : [e.values]) }
puts array_data.inspect
```

The result is:

```
[["id", "name"], [1, "Don"], [2, "Bob"]]
```